# A problem about the matrix equation $a^{\sf T}A_1a=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A_1$ be an $m\times m$ real constant matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. The matrix $A_1$ satisfies $a^{\sf T}A_1a=0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$, where $a^{\sf T}$ is the transpose of $a$. Show that
$$A_1=-A_1^{\sf T}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a, b \in \Bbb R^m$, consider$ (a + b)^TA_1(a + b)$: we have

$0 = (a + b)^TA_1(a + b) = (a^T + b^T)A_1(a + b)$
$= a^TA_1a + a^TA_1b + b^TA_1a + b^TA_1b = a^TA_1b + b^TA_1a. \tag{1}$

We observe that

$a^TA_1b = (a^TA_1b)^T = b^TA_1^Ta, \tag{2}$

since these are all scalar quantities and hence are symmetric with respect to transposition.  Thus (1) may be written

$b^TA_1^Ta + b^TA_1a = 0, \tag{3}$

or

$b^T(A_1^Ta + A_1a) = 0, \tag{4}$

which holds for all $b$, whence

$0 = A_1^Ta + A_1a = (A_1^T + A_1)a = 0 \tag{5}$

holds for all $a \in \Bbb R^m$; but (5) implies

$A_1^T + A_1 = 0, \tag{6}$

or

$A_1^T =  -A_1, \tag{7}$

as was required. QED.

Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: To @Robert Lewis: I don't understand why $0=A_1^Ta+A_1a$ and $A_1^T+A_1=0$. Could you please explain more clearly?

Comment: To @Wei-Cheng Liu:  if $y^Tx = 0$ for *all* $y$, choose $y =  x$; then $x^Tx = 0$.  Does that suffice?

Comment: To @Wei-Cheng Liu:  If $Cx = 0$ for *all* $x$, and the rows of $C$ are $c_i$, successively choose $x = c_i^T$ and apply the previous comment.  Does that suffice?

Comment: To @Robert Lewis: Yes, your explanations suffice. Thank you very much!

Comment: To @Wei-Cheng Liu:  and you sir are most welcome!  So glad to be of service!  Cheerio, RKL

Answer (score 3):

If $(b_1,\cdots,b_m)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^m$, can you compute $(b_i+b_j)^{\sf T}A (b_i+b_j)$ in two different ways ?

Comment: To @Bebop: I can only find one way to compute $(b_i+b_j)^{\sf T}A(b_i+b_j)$, i.e., expand it and compute it directly. I find the equation is equal to $a_{ii}+a_{ij}+a_{ji}+a_{jj}$, where $a_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$th element of the matrix $A$. But I don't understand what is the relationship between your answer and my question. Could you please explain more clearly?

Comment: To @Bebop: OK, I see. From your answer I can conclude that $A=-A^{\sf T}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is the explanation : the assumption on $A$ tells you that $0=(b_i+b_j)^{\sf T}A(b_i+b_j)=b_i^{\sf T}Ab_j+b_j^{\sf T}Ab_i$ so $b_i^{\sf T}Ab_j=-b_j^{\sf T}Ab_i$. If you compute by hands these two last terms, you easily see that it means $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have already derived $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ and thus $A=-A^{\sf T}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider, ${\cal A} \equiv A_{1} + A_{1}^{\sf T}$ which is a
hermitian matrix: ${\cal A}^{\dagger} = {\cal A}$. ${\cal A}$ has real eigenvalues: Let's $\left\{n\right\}$ and $\left\{\lambda_{n}\right\}$ the orthonormalized eigenvectors and real eigenvalues of ${\cal A}$, respectively:

\begin{equation}
{\cal A}n = \lambda_{n}n\,,
\qquad
n^{\sf T}n' = \delta_{nn'}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Obviously, $a^{\sf T}{\cal A}\,a = 0,\ \forall\ a \in {\mathbb R}^{m}$. In particular, $n^{\sf T}{\cal A}n = 0,\ \forall$ eigenvectors $n$ of ${\cal A}$. 
From $\left(1\right)$, we get

\begin{equation}
n^{\sf T}{\cal A}n = \lambda_{n}n^{\sf T}n = \lambda_{n}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\lambda_{n} = 0.
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\cal A}n = 0.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

From $\left(2\right)$, it's clear that
\begin{equation}
{\cal A} = \sum_{n}{\cal A}\,nn^{\sf T} = 0 
\end{equation}

Then,
$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
A_{1} = -A_{1}^{\sf T}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Does the spectral theorem hold for any square matrix?

Comment: To @Felix Marin: I don't know why $\lambda_n=n^{\sf T}A_1n$ and $A_1=\sum_n\lambda_nnn^{\sf T}$. Could you please explain more clearly?

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu The first assertion is false; indeed your matrix $A_1$ is antisymmetric, so it only has purely imaginary eigenvalues and one can't apply the hypothesis $n^TA_1n=0$ to an eigenvector, because $n$ cannot be in $\mathbb{R}^m$. The second assertion, instead, is true, because an antisymmetric matrix is normal; however you can't apply the spectral theorem until you have *proved* you can, that is, that the matrix is normal.

Comment: @egreg OK, I understand. Thank you for spending time on explaining the logic to me.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for the delay. I left my computer for awhile. Somebody next door had a big noisy party such that I left it. I rewrote the whole thing. I'm a physicist and I was guided for tools we use in Quantum Mechanics. It's a simple linear algebra problem in a finite dimension vectorial space. By the way, they are tools the computer scientist use daily. I was always aware I have to answer you.

Comment: @FelixMarin Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(a^TA_1a)^T=(a^TA_1^Ta)=0$ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}^m$, where I employed the fact that the transpose of the scalar is itself. Now since both quantities are zero we can add them together and get that $a^T(A_1+A_1^T)a=0$ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Now matrix $B=A+A^T$ is symmetric and $a^TBa$ is then quadratic form which is zero for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Hence $B=0$ and you have that $A=-A^T$.

Comment: $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\-1& 0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has the property without being a zero matrix.

Comment: I've removed the offending statement. We can show that $a^T(\alpha A_1+\beta A_1^T)a=0$ for all $a$ and all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but only for $\alpha=\beta=1$ the matrix $\alpha A_1+\beta A_1^T$ is symmetric and we can invoke the quadratic form property.

Comment: To @mpiktas How can we know that $B=0$?

Comment: To @egreg: I do not quite understand your comment. Could you please explain more clearly?

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu if quadratic form $a^TBa=0$ then $B=0$. We can write any symmetric matrix as $B=P^TDP$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix. Then $a^TBa=0$  for all $a$ is equivalent to $a^TDa=0$ for all $a$ and then it is clear that $D=0$. The comment of egreg applies to my older version of the answer, where I made some incorrect claims.

Comment: To @mpiktas: OK, I understand. Thank you for your further explanation.